# how to open partial view in kendo Window with some parameter(or in Edit mode) in kendoUI Q3 2013 using mvc4 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

trying to open partial view with DropDownListFor and DateTimePickerFor controls in kendo Window by passing some parameter(or you may say in Edit mode) from another another partial view but i am getting popup with simply textbox for DropDownListFor and DateTimePickerFor.

what i have done is
**in .cshtml**

```
@Html.Kendo().Window().Name("wdwAppt").Title("Reschedule Appointment")
```

**and in .js file**

```
function RescheduleAppt(id)
{
    debugger
    var RescheduleUrl = $("#RescheduleAppointmentURL").data('request-url');
    $("#wdwAppt").kendoWindow({
        content: {
            url: RescheduleUrl,
            data: { PatAppointmentKey: id }
        }
    });

    $("#wdwAppt").data("kendoWindow").open();
}
```

the function `RescheduleAppt()` is calling from onclick event of `ClientTemplate` column of kendo grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my view has 3 tab say 'tab1','tab2' and 'tab3'.
when i tried to open window for some purpose(which contains the content from tab1) from tab2 my page had two widget with same name and thats the reason for not showing dropdowlist and datetimepicker.

The widgets in the content might not be initialized correctly in the following cases:
1)There are elements already on the page that have the same IDs(the property names in this scenario). The initialization scripts will find them instead in this case and the inputs in the content will not be initialized.
2)There is an event handler that is defined after the widgets in the content. The document ready event does not work for dynamically added content so the event handlers will not be defined yet when the initialization scripts are executed.
3)There is a JavaScript error thrown that prevents the scripts execution.

Comment: Hi Junior!                                                           To achieve this, You have to use element with different IDs only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In this code parent page have a kendo grid. In that grid display edit button for clicking this button opened popup with control.

```
**This is my button in grid(on click of this button):-**

    <a href='javascript: void(0)' onclick='EditItem(this)' name='#=SurveySectionID#' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit'><span class='k-icon k-iconSetImagePosition k-edit'></span>Edit</a>

**JS Function:-**

    function EditItem(obj) {
            var SurveySectionID = obj.name;
            OpenKendoWindow({ WindowName: 'windowSection', Url: '@CommonHelper.BaseUrl' + 'Admin/Content/AddEditSection', Data: { SurveySectionID: SurveySectionID, SurveyID: '@Model.SurveyID'} });
        }

    **This is common function for open kendo window.**

    function OpenKendoWindow(para) {

        if (para != null) {
            var dialog = $("#" + para.WindowName).data("kendoWindow")
            dialog.refresh({
                url: para.Url,
                data: para.Data
            });

            dialog.open();

            CenterWindow(dialog);

            return dialog;
        }
    }

    **Below is popup chtml page which is opened by button click event.**

    <div class="float_l">                   
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.serviceTypeName, new { id = "txtserviceTypeName", @class = "k-textbox", @maxlength = 48, uifocus = "focus" })
                        <br />
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.serviceTypeName)
                    </div>

    <div class="margin_t10 clearfix">
                    <div class="float_l margin_l20 cols165">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LOBId)<span class="color_red">*</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="float_l ">
                        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.LOBId)
                              .Name("LOBId")
                              .Placeholder("--Select--")
                              .DataTextField("Text")
                              .DataValueField("Value")
                              .BindTo(Model.LOBList)
                              .Events(e => e.Change("ValueChangedOncombo"))
                            )
                        <br />
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LOBId)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your respons jeet!                                            not working.same problem occurring.i am using cascading dropdownlist.is cascading dropdownlist reason?

Comment: No, you also used cascading dropdown in popup view.